# How can I disable a Submit button, until after legitimate date is entered in an input date field?

Tags: html, angularjs, internet-explorer, html-input

I have a form that is used as a filter.  This is the code for the date input field.

```
<label>Date:</label>
<input type="text" id="dateFilter"
       ng-model="gridFilters.dateFilter"
       placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"
       ng-disabled="loadingData" />
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar" style="width: 30px"></span>
```

When the angular controller initializes, the `gridFilters.dateFilter` value is set to `undefined` and should not default to anything.  This is the correct behavior.

This is the code for my submit button.  I'd like for the button to remain disabled until a user selects/enters a valid date.

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-success pull-right"
        style="top: -5px; margin-left: 20px"
        ng-click="filter()"
        ng-enabled="gridFilters.dateFilter!== null && gridFilters.dateFilter!== undefined && Date.parse(gridFilters.dateFilter)"
        ng-hide="session.Status !== 0">
    Search
</button>
```

As you can see, I've made multiple attempts at checking the value of the `gridFilters.dateFilter` value.  None of this works.  Specifically, when I load the page, my button is enabled as if everything is if a proper date has been entered into the selector.  How can I test if the date value is, in fact, a date? Also, this must work in Internet Explorer.  I doubt this will make a difference, but IE is our corporate, preferred browser.

Comment: No problem! On Angular it's super easy: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation AngularJs... Well, it's probably equally easy in some ways but with AngularJs being EOL and soon out of support, it's hard to say what there is for it.

Comment: @AustinTFrench And those methods should work with Angular 1.4?  We're stuck in the past on this project.

Comment: No, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **ng-disabled** - there is no HTML attribute called enabled.

And try this:

```
<button type="button"
        class="btn btn-success pull-right"
        style="top: -5px; margin-left: 20px"
        ng-click="filter()"
        ng-disabled="gridFilters.dateFilter === null || gridFilters.dateFilter === undefined || Date.parse(gridFilters.dateFilter)"
        ng-hide="session.Status !== 0">
    Search
</button>
```

This `ng-disabled="gridFilters.dateFilter === null || gridFilters.dateFilter === undefined"` is working 100%

But for the  `Date.parse(gridFilters.dateFilter)` I'm not sure if it will work or not.

Another approach is :

```
<form name="dataForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm()">
   <input type="date" name="date" class="form-control" required 
          ng-model="gridFilters.dateFilter">
   <button type="submit"
           class="btn btn-success pull-right"
           style="top: -5px; margin-left: 20px"
           ng-click="filter()"
           ng-disabled="dataForm.$invalid"
           ng-hide="session.Status !== 0">
      Search
   </button>
</form>
```

Comment: @RLH Which solution did you accept? `Date.parse` will not work in AngularJS expressions because AngularJS expressions do not have access to the global object.